# ApexCharts - show extra information in the dataLabels on a bar chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

please help me, I'm going mad...
I have a simple vertical bar chart.
For each bar, I need to show not only the actual value of the bar coming from the series object but another value for each bar coming from another data source.

I used the following options for graph generating:

```js
{
  chart: {
    height: 400,
    type: "bar",
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    },
    animations: {
      enabled: true,
      easing: "easeinout",
      speed: 130,
      animateGradually: {
          enabled: true,
          delay: 130
      },
      dynamicAnimation: {
          enabled: true,
          speed: 130
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: "data1",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  }],
  colors: [ 
    "#26D200", "#26D200", "#26D200", "#26D200", "#26D200", "#26D200", "#26D200", "#26D200", 
    "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", "#00ACD2", 
    "#2600D2", "#2600D2", "#2600D2", "#2600D2", 
    "#D20000", "#D20000", 
    "#999999", "#999999", "#999999", 
    "#D2D2D2", "#D2D2D2", "#D2D2D2", "#D2D2D2", "#D2D2D2",
    "#D2D200", "#D2D200", "#D2D200", "#D2D200", "#D2D200", "#D2D200"
  ],                            
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      distributed: true, // this line is mandatory
      borderRadius: 3,
      dataLabels: {
        position: "top" // top, center, bottom
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
      show: false
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function (val, opt) {
      return val + "unt";
    },                              
    offsetY: -20,
    style: {
      fontSize: "12px",
      colors: ["#FFFFFF"]
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: [
      "301", "300", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307",
      ["308", "0-100"], ["309", "+40"], ["310", "20-40"], ["311", "20-40"], ["312", "8-20"], ["313", "8-20"], ["314", "3-9"], ["315", "0-3"],
      ["601", "3-9"], ["602", "8-20"], ["603", "0-3"], ["604", "--"],
      ["501", "Oss"], ["502", "Idr"],
      ["401", "Dol"], ["402", "123"], ["403", "HQ"],
      ["404", "ED."], ["405", "Mix"], ["406", "Mix"], ["407", "FIO."], ["408", "Mix"],
      "S1", "S2", "S3", "S5", "S6", "S206"
    ],
    position: "bottom",
    lines: {
      show: true
    },
    axisBorder: {
      show: true
    },
    axisTicks: {
      show: true
    },
    labels: {
      show: true,
      rotate: -90,
      rotateAlways: false,
      hideOverlappingLabels: true,
      showDuplicates: true,
      trim: false,
      minHeight: undefined,
      maxHeight: 120,
      style: {
        colors: "#EEEEEE",
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        fontWeight: 400,
        cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-label"
      },
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0
    },                    
    crosshairs: {
      fill: {
        type: "gradient",
        gradient: {
          colorFrom: "#D8E3F0",
          colorTo: "#BED1E6",
          stops: [0, 100],
          opacityFrom: 0.4,
          opacityTo: 0.5
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    lines: {
      show: false
    },
    axisBorder: {
      show: false
    },
    axisTicks: {
      show: false
    },
    tickAmount: 10,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,                                  
    labels: {
      show: false,
      formatter: function (val) {
        return val + "%";
      }
    }
  },
  grid: {
    borderColor: "#666666",
    strokeDashArray: 5
  },
  tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      enabledOnSeries: undefined,
      shared: true,
      followCursor: true,
      intersect: false,
      inverseOrder: false,
      custom: undefined,
      fillSeriesColor: false,
      theme: "dark",
      style: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontFamily: undefined
      },
      onDatasetHover: {
          highlightDataSeries: true
      },
      marker: {
          show: true
      },
      fixed: {
          enabled: false,
          position: "topRight",
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0
      }
  }                                
}
```

I tried to add another series and hiding it in the idea to use data coming from that serie and using the formatter routine to grab data without success because, I think, that hiding data do some trick internally to let that data unreachable.

Could someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve here. But maybe something like this?

You can then use the dataPointIndex, or the value for looking up things in the secondary array, or the primaryArray(the array you used to build the series)

```js
    dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function (val, opt) {
    let secondaryValue = someOtherDataSource[opt.dataPointIndex]; // If the indexes are the same for both sets
      secondaryValue = someOtherDataSource?.find((val) => {
          //Check the index of the chart against an id. Or you could use the value
          return val.id === opt.dataPointIndex;
      })
      const primaryObj = primaryData[opt.dataPointIndex] // {id:2, value: 43}
      secondaryValue = someOtherDataSource?.find((val) => {
          //Check the index of the chart against an id. Or you could use the value
          return val.id === primaryObj.id;
      })
    return `val: ${val} | someOtherData: ${secondaryValue}`;
  };
},
```

If this is not what you want then I think [annotations](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/annotations/) might be what you are looking for. See examples [here](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/line-chart-annotations/). Then hide the line or dot, and only display the circle?